# Facebook Login app crashing on client's device

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have created an app that uses Facebook Login. ( facebook SDK 4.0.0 )

It works fine on my device ( developer side ) both with Facebook app installed and uninstalled.

As soon as my client clicks on the login button with his device, his app got crashed and on some other mobile login does not occur successfully.

I have added 3 key hashes on the app settings.

I have no clue why it is happening. There is no error on my code.

Help needed!
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: try adding `crashlytics ` next time whenever giving build to client .You will get crash stackstrace

Comment: Even if my mobile data is off, it crashes just on clicking the button but works fine on my device